# Values stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have created two level of registration in my website, in first level of registration I can store my value in database but in second level I can't store in the same table.

In first register I have used an insert query, in second level of register in same table, I have used an update query.

If I given direct row value in where condition I am able to store, in case if I give as `user_id` I should not accept.

First register:

```
public function register($uname,$umail,$upass,$mobile,$gender)
    {
        try
        {
            $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass,mobile,gender) 
                                                       VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass, :mobile, :gender )");

            $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
            $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":mobile", $mobile);
            $stmt->bindparam(":gender", $gender);



            $stmt->execute();   

            return $stmt;   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }               
    }
```

second register:

```
public function register1($marital_status,$applicant_photo,$date_of_birth,$home_name,$birth_time)
    {
        try
        {
                        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET marital_status= :marital_status, applicant_photo=:applicant_photo, date_of_birth=:date_of_birth, home_name=:home_name, birth_time=:birth_time WHERE user_id =':user_id'");


            $stmt->bindparam(":marital_status", $marital_status);
            $stmt->bindparam(":applicant_photo", $applicant_photo);
            $stmt->bindparam(":date_of_birth", $date_of_birth);
            $stmt->bindparam(":home_name", $home_name);
            $stmt->bindparam(":birth_time", $birth_time);   
            $stmt->execute();   

            return $stmt;   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }               
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: missing to bind the user_id stmt->bindparam(":user_id", $user_id);    and also remove single quotes user_id =':user_id'

Comment: Where have you bind `user_id`  in `register1`?

Comment: Basically what JYoThl said. In general, check `$this->conn->error` for more information. `try...catch` would not catch error, as `mysqli` by default does not throw error.

Comment: I don't know " why this question got five upvotes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**3 Errors in your code**

1. user_id is not inserted to the table
2. On second level registration change `user_id =':user_id'` into `user_id =:user_id`,i.e remove single quotes
3. Missing `bindparam` to user_id,i.e `$stmt->bindparam(":user_id", $user_id);`

Try to change this code

```
public function register($uname,$umail,$upass,$mobile,$gender,$user_id)
{
    try
    {
        $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass,mobile,gender,user_id) 
                                                   VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass, :mobile, :gender, :user_id )");

        $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
        $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);
        $stmt->bindparam(":mobile", $mobile);
        $stmt->bindparam(":gender", $gender);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_id", $user_id);



        $stmt->execute();   

        return $stmt;   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }               
}
```

**Second Registration**

```
public function register1($marital_status,$applicant_photo,$date_of_birth,$home_name,$birth_time)
{
    try
    {
                    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET marital_status= :marital_status, applicant_photo=:applicant_photo, date_of_birth=:date_of_birth, home_name=:home_name, birth_time=:birth_time WHERE user_id =:user_id");


        $stmt->bindparam(":marital_status", $marital_status);
        $stmt->bindparam(":applicant_photo", $applicant_photo);
        $stmt->bindparam(":date_of_birth", $date_of_birth);
        $stmt->bindparam(":home_name", $home_name);
        $stmt->bindparam(":birth_time", $birth_time);   
        $stmt->execute();   

        return $stmt;   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the `$user_id` as argument to the `function` and `bind` it like this

**1st :** Missing to `bind` the `user_id`

`$stmt->bindparam(":user_id", $user_id);`

**2nd :** And also remove single quotes

```
user_id =':user_id'
```

change to

```
  user_id =:user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET marital_status= :marital_status, applicant_photo=:applicant_photo, date_of_birth=:date_of_birth, home_name=:home_name, birth_time=:birth_time WHERE user_id =:user_id");

$stmt->bindparam(":marital_status", $marital_status);
$stmt->bindparam(":applicant_photo", $applicant_photo);
$stmt->bindparam(":date_of_birth", $date_of_birth);
$stmt->bindparam(":home_name", $home_name);
$stmt->bindparam(":birth_time", $birth_time);   
$stmt->bindparam(":user_id", $user_id);   
$stmt->execute();   
return $stmt;
```

I thing it will work for you.

Comment: The issue is you are not binding the user_id value on your query.